# Long exact sequence of Quillen derived functors

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, homological-algebra, simplicial-stuff, model-categories

Let $F:\mathcal A\to \mathcal B$ be an additive right exact functor between abelian categories $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$. Then for a short exact sequence
$$
0\to A\to B\to C\to 0
$$
in $\mathcal A$ there is a long exact sequence of derived functors of $F$:
$$
\dots \to L_1 F(B)\to L_1 F(C)\to F(A)\to F(B)\to F(C)\to 0
$$

I wonder what can we say in a more general case when $\mathcal A$ is a model category and $\mathcal B$ is a stable model category and $F$ be a left Quillen functor. In practice I mostly care about the case when these categories are categories of simplicial objects and $\mathcal B$ admits Dold-Kan correspondence (i.e. equivalent to bounded below chain complexes in some abelian category). If we start with cofiber sequence 
$$
A\to B\to C
$$
of course, we have a long exact sequence
$$
\dots \pi_1 LF(C)\to F(A) \to F(B) \to F(C) \to 0
$$

but how much can we tell for a fiber sequence $A\to B \to C$ ? Intuitively, there may be some (Leray-Serre like ?) spectral sequence instead of a long exact sequence. Thx.

Comment: Quick note: the Leray-Serre spectral sequence arises because there is a natural filtration on $C$ (the cellular filtration), if your model category admits similar things (for example categories of simplicial objects should have one, just by taking the skeletal filtration) you should be able to work the proof verbatim.

Comment: If $LF$ doesn't preserve fiber sequences I don't see much hope, but if it does then you're good. Since fiber sequences and cofiber sequences agree in stable $\infty$-categories(or triangulated categories), it takes fiber sequences to cofiber sequences and you can use the spectral sequence you expect. I think $LF$ preserving fiber sequences is implied by $F$ being left exact in the usual sense.

Comment: @JoeBerner I don't understand your comment about $LF$ preserving fiber sequences. $C_*(-;\mathbb{Z})$ does not preserve fiber sequences, but there is certainly a Serre spectral sequence.

Comment: I didn't mean to present it as a necessary condition for a spectral sequence to exist, but merely as a sufficient one. As far as the case of homology, I have to admit I'm a bit confused since technically we should be landing in some sort of local-coefficients category and not just chains of abelian groups. In the case where the base is simply connected and this is just abelian groups, it's not obvious to me that this isn't giving fiber sequences.

Comment: @DenisNardin, there is another way of obtaining (cohomological) Leray-Serre spectral sequence - as a Grothendieck spectral sequence of composition of global sections functor, and direct image functor. Similar thing can be done with homological version, if our category admits proper notion of abelianization and we see homology à la Quillen as derived functors of abelianization. But unfortunately this spectral sequence does not capture the first (zeroth ?) terms: $F(A)\to F(B)\to F(C)$, which are of interest for me.

Comment: @JoeBerner If $LF$ preserve fiber sequences, then, of course we have a long exact sequence and there is nothing to discuss. As you mentioned, in stable categories it is indeed equivalent to preservation of cofiber sequences, thats why we have a long exact sequences in homological algebra, a somewhat linear case. But if we want $F$ to be left exact then, there will no derived functors at all.